# float placement using endfloat

Tags: graphics, floats, eps, endfloat

I have a lyx file in which there are several figures and tables.  The preamble has been amended to have:

```
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage{longtable,lscape}
 \usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst]{endfloat}
 \usepackage{caption} 
 \captionsetup[table]{skip=20pt}
```

When I added a new figure after all my other figures, in the lyx screen it numbers it Figure 5.  However, when I actually export to PDF LaTeX seems to number it Figure 1. Any ideas on this? This latest figure is an eps graphic.  The other figures are all pdf documents.

EDIT: Interesting: I figured out the issue (or atleast what fixes it). This figure was specified to be sideways. Once I removed that the ordering became correct. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Can you please build a minimal working example illustrating the problem? Nothing too complicated; document class used and a couple of figures; one of them a "regular" figure and the other one with the sideways specification. In this way we can reproduce your problem and detect the cause of the problem.

Comment: Note that LyX is just a front-end or editor. So its placement of floats is usually different (and not floating at all). During compile time, TeX does its magic to optimize the float placement. `sidewaysfigure`s usually land on a page of floats, which could even further disturb the difference between the editor and the output.

Comment: yes, attempting to produce example but it seems a simple example is not working to illustrate my problem. will post something as soon as i get it "working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer in the endfloat documentation:

> The rotating package[5] contains definitions of environments sidewaysfigure and sidewaystable,8 and
>   it would be nice to have these work in documents which also use endfloat. Appropriate redefinitions of these so
>   that they work with endfloat are given in the file efxmpl.cfg. If you wish to use that file, you should include it
>   as a package (possibly renamed) after you include endfloat. Or you could simple rename it to endfloat.cfg
>   and endfloat will include it automatically.

Comment: I had a similar problem and the following solution worked for me: add `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}`
`\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}` to the preamble (Document - Settings - LaTeX Preamble in LyX). Then endfloat "grabs" (not the right term I'm sure) sideways floats and puts them in the right order.

Comment: PS - it appears that LyX adds the `rotfloat` package when you insert a sideways table through LyX, but if you were including the table manually (i.e. entering LaTeX code directly), I suppose you would have to add the package manually as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following also worked for me, but make sure

```
\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst]{endfloat}  
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}
```

comes after

```
\usepackage{rotfloat}
```

in the LaTeX code.